# How to get data from json object with fetch in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I'm trying to get values of an object in JSON file with javascript.

My JSON file looks like this;

```
{
    "product":"gill",
    "body":
        {
        "name":"gill",
        "thumbnail":"https://www.example.com/gill.jpg"
    },
    "product":"folded",
    "body":
        {
        "name":"folded",
        "thumbnail":"https://www.example.com/folded.jpg"
    }
}
```

and my JS file looks like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
 const apiUri ="../test.json";
 const product = document.getElementById("products").children[0].id;
    const data = { product : product };
        fetch(apiUri, {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            Image.setAttribute("src",json.body.thumbnail)
           
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        console.log(data);
}
```

when page loads, the Image src gets always the last product in json file, which is folded.

I want to search for a product which has been get by element id, and set the image src of that product in JSON file.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. You can't have (meaningful) duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

See [the JSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-4):

> The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

and

> When the names within an object are not    unique, the behavior of
> software that receives such an object is    unpredictable.  Many
> implementations report the last name/value pair    only.  Other
> implementations report an error or fail to parse the    object, and
> some implementations report all of the name/value pairs,    including
> duplicates.

Change the design of your JSON.

If you want to have multiple products, use an **array** of products.